# Add possible input types to CGRect Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I want to be able to pass a percentage value to a CGRect

I created a Percentage class to get the input and then created four values (x, y, width, height)

Now I need to create an extension for CGRect to be able to use the Percentage values in it. The extension returns an error.

```
extension CGRect {
    init(x: Percentage, y: Percentage, width: Percentage, height: Percentage) {
        self.init(x: Percentage.x, y: Percentage.y, width: Percentage.width, height: Percentage.height)
```

> ERROR: Instance member 'x' cannot be used on type 'Percentage'

```
    }
}


class Percentage {
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    init(_ value: CGFloat) {
        self.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * value
        self.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * value
        self.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * value
        self.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * value
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help ;)

EDIT:

I wanna be able to use it like this:

```
CGRect(x: Percentage(0.5), y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: Pleas overthink the Architecture of you classes in terms of loose coupling things together. It would be better not binding the view of interest (UIScreen.main) to the `Percantage`class. If you inject it - this class could be used for any `UIView`. Or event better would be an extension on `UIView`.

Comment: @seeya Thanks for your tipp. this would be cool yeah, but I want to get the basics (my question) to work first xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instance member 'x' cannot be used on type 'Percentage'

you're using type of class so even if you had in parameter `percentage`, it wouldn't work.

But better would be if you just passed certain `Percentage` as parameter for `init` and then use its properties (use it with small `p` because you need init parameter, not your class type)

```
init(percentage: Percentage) {
    self.init(x: percentage.x, y: percentage.y, width: percentage.width, height: percentage.height)
}
```

---

After your edit I have to say that you don’t have to use custom init and you can just pass property of your `Percentage`

```
CGRect(x: yourPercentage.x, y: 50, ...)
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to be able to use it like this: CGRect(x: Percentage(0.5), y: labelY, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)

Comment: I don't think your question is clear... what is the meaning of Percentage(0.5)? Do you mean x is 50% of the width of the labelWidth?

Comment: @antPhitlok Percentage(0.5) is 50% of UIScreen.main.bounds.height / width

Comment: @swiftlynx  then you don’t need custom init

Comment: @RobertDresler How do I do it then?

Comment: Use for example CGRect(x: yourPercentage.x, ...)

Comment: @RobertDresler Oh well, that works xD Thank you, haven't even thought about that...

Answer (score -1):

Think there is no need for a custom extension/classes - just use:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let viewRect = view.frame

let scaleFactor:CGFloat = 0.5
let scaledFrame = viewRect.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor))

print("Scaled size: \(scaledFrame)")
// Scaled size: (0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)
```

However, you also can move this "feature" to an extension as well.